# cmake project file not valid

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake

I am building glm for vs 2012 but I get these errors with cmake
when I run vs2012 and compile a normal console application I also get error telling:

> error C1069: cannot read compiler command line

And with cmake I get these errors, and I think the above error is related to it.

> Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
>
> Change Dir: C:/Users/Amar Thapa/Desktop/glm bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:C:\Program Files\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe cmTryCompileExec2330384412.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
>      Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 12.0.21005.1
>
> [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18408]
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Build started 12/23/2013 12:50:51 AM.
>
> Project "C:\Users\Amar Thapa\Desktop\glm bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec2330384412.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
>
> PrepareForBuild:
>
> ```
>  Creating directory "cmTryCompileExec2330384412.dir\Debug\".
>
>  Creating directory "C:\Users\Amar Thapa\Desktop\glm bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".
>
>  Creating directory "cmTryCompileExec2330384412.dir\Debug\cmTryCom.89557F4B.tlog\".
> ```
>
> InitializeBuildStatus:
>
> ```
>  Creating "cmTryCompileExec2330384412.dir\Debug\cmTryCom.89557F4B.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
> ```
>
> ClCompile:
>
> ```
>  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTryCompileExec2330384412.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTryCompileExec2330384412.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCCompiler.c
>
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"cmTryCompileExec2330384412.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTryCompileExec2330384412.dir\Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:queue testCCompiler.c
>
>  testCCompiler.c
> ```
>
> testCCompiler.c(12): fatal error C1069: cannot read compiler command line [C:\Users\Amar Thapa\Desktop\glm bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec2330384412.vcxproj]
>
> Done Building Project "C:\Users\Amar Thapa\Desktop\glm bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec2330384412.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "C:\Users\Amar Thapa\Desktop\glm bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec2330384412.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
>
> (ClCompile target) ->
>
> ```
>  testCCompiler.c(12): fatal error C1069: cannot read compiler command line [C:\Users\Amar Thapa\Desktop\glm bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTryCompileExec2330384412.vcxproj]
>
>    0 Warning(s)
>
>    1 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.34

Comment: The C compiler "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio
  12.0/VC/bin/cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.

Comment: trying to make this file http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/index.html